# Is there a python pip package or similar for mapping a name to a nickname. So for example package_name['Joseph'] would return 'Joe' for example?

Tags: python, django, mapping

I am building an app where I have a database of thousands of names, I then use have a second source of data that I am mapping the first data to to find something, however I'm facing an issue where sometimes in one database I have the name 'Joseph' for example, but when im trying to find it in the second source of data, the name is 'Joe'.

Already tried looking on pip but no luck

Comment: How is it supposed to choose the nickname? Elizabeth, for example, can be shortened as Betty, Beth, or Liz.

Comment: @Selcuk this is where if it existed it would've/could've looked like {'Elizabeth': ['Betty', 'Beth', 'Liz'], 'Joseph': ['Joe', 'Joey']}.

Answer (score 1):

As it seems nobody has created a package already you can be the first. You can start from list like [http://www.cc.kyoto-su.ac.jp/~trobb/nicklist.html](http://www.cc.kyoto-su.ac.jp/%7Etrobb/nicklist.html), you can probably find more.

Comment: That's a good start, thanks for finding this! Will get on with making my own